# Fastest way to compute a factorial in a numba nopython function

Tags: python, performance, factorial, numba

I have a function that I want to compile with `numba`, however I need to calculate a factorial inside that function. Unfortunatly `numba` doesn't support `math.factorial`:

```
import math
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def factorial1(x):
    return math.factorial(x)

factorial1(10)
# UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
```

I saw that it supported `math.gamma` (which could be used to calculate the factorial), however contrary to the real `math.gamma` function it doesn't return floats that represent "integral values":

```
@nb.njit
def factorial2(x):
    return math.gamma(x+1)

factorial2(10)
# 3628799.9999999995  <-- not exact

math.gamma(11)
# 3628800.0  <-- exact
```

and it's slow compared to `math.factorial`:

```
%timeit factorial2(10)
# 1.12 µs ± 11.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit math.factorial(10)
# 321 ns ± 6.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So I decided to define my own function:

```
@nb.njit
def factorial3(x):
    n = 1
    for i in range(2, x+1):
        n *= i
    return n

factorial3(10)
# 3628800

%timeit factorial3(10)
# 821 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

It's still slower than `math.factorial` but it's faster than a `math.gamma` based numba function and the value is "exact".

So I'm looking for the fastest way to compute the `factorial` of a positive integer number (<= 20; to avoid overflow) inside a nopython numba function.

Comment: If your only concerned with factorials for integers `0..20` then a lookup table is probably worth checking for speed.

Comment: Arrrgggh, in my previous comment where I wrote *your* I should have written *you're*.  Or *If your only concern is to ...*

Comment: You could try re-implementing the python approach in numba - it goes through some extra steps to order the multiplication in a particular way - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1275

Answer (score 3):

For values <= 20, python is using a lookup table, as was suggested in the comments.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1452

```
LOOKUP_TABLE = np.array([
    1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320,
    362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600,
    6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000,
    20922789888000, 355687428096000, 6402373705728000,
    121645100408832000, 2432902008176640000], dtype='int64')

@nb.jit
def fast_factorial(n):
    if n > 20:
        raise ValueError
    return LOOKUP_TABLE[n]
```

Called from python it's slightly slower than the python version due to the numba dispatch overhead.

```
In [58]: %timeit math.factorial(10)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 79.4 ns per loop

In [59]: %timeit fast_factorial(10)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 173 ns per loop
```

But called inside another numba function can be much faster.

```
def loop_python():
    for i in range(10000):
        for n in range(21):
            math.factorial(n)

@nb.njit
def loop_numba():
    for i in range(10000):
        for n in range(21):
            fast_factorial(n)

In [65]: %timeit loop_python()
10 loops, best of 3: 36.7 ms per loop

In [66]: %timeit loop_numba()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 73.6 ns per loop
```

Comment: Numba does agressive loop optimization so if you don't save the result of `fast_factorial` it won't even do the loop.